# Netbeans GUI is not creating properly

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, swingbuilder

[image]

I am trying to create Swing GUI in netbeans. But when I run it, it does not work as I designed it. Somehow horizontally & vertically it's a little bit bigger than I designed. shown in image the bottom one is running & the top one is the design.

I have tried manually changing the size of jFrame & jPanel but not helping.

[code](https://gist.github.com/MRW01F/496d109f063c0731296f0e4396078cb7)

I am a total noob and I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Code for a question should be included **in the question.** But don't dump the entire code. Prepare and post a [mre] that displays the problem.

Comment: Apart from the [mre], also check out [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org) is.